# SQL - sum (column 1 + column2 + column3 ) and select max value of sum in each group

Tags: mysql, sql

**Here is my table with sample data:**

```
id|group_id|column1|column2|column3| 
--------------------------------------
1    1    |    1        1        0
2    1    |    1        1        1
3    2    |    0        0        0
4    2    |    1        1        1
5    1    |    1        0        0
6    3    |    0        0        0
```

**Expected result set:** (The result should show the maximum sum (col 1 + col 2 + col 3) in each group)

```
id|group_id|column1|column2|column3| 
--------------------------------------
2    1    |    1        1        1
4    2    |    1        1        1
6    3    |    0        0        0
```

**Actual result set:** (select *, max(m.column1 + m.column2 + m.column3) as total from my_table m group by m.group_id) which is wrong

```
id|group_id|column1|column2|column3|total| 
------------------------------------------
1    1    |    1        1        0      3 
3    2    |    0        0        0      3
6    3    |    0        0        0      0
```

I'm quite new to SQL, it seems like the query selecting the first id in each group.

what is the best way to get expected result?

Comment: Are you sure that your expected result set is correct?

Comment: your expected result set doesn't even contain any summed value

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to get the rows that yield highest sum of 3 columns in each group:

```
select a.*
from my_table a
join (
  select group_id, max(column1 + column2 + column3) summation
  from my_table
  group by group_id) b on a.group_id = b.group_id and a.column1 + a.column2 + a.column3 = b.summation;
```

Comment: Please accept the solution if it has worked for you.

Comment: This answer relies on a MySQL extension to `group by` that is explicitly documented not to work (namely the use of columns in the `group by` that are not included in the `group by` clause and do not have aggregation functions).  You can read about it here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for pointing it out. I had always assumed MySQL will pick the first row it sees, but I guess it could be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do get your desired result i.e. with a subselect:

**First step:**

```
SELECT
    MAX(m1.column1 + m1.column2 + m1.column3)
FROM
    my_table m1
GROUP BY
    m1.group_id
```

will get you the maximum total per group_id.

Because values in non aggregated columns are indetermined, if this columns contains different values for a group, you can't simply aggregate as you've done, but a subselect using the query from first step will do it:

**Complete query**

```
SELECT
     *,
     m.column1 + m.column2 + m.column3 as total
FROM
    my_table m
WHERE
    m.column1 + m.column2 + m.column3 = (
    SELECT
        MAX(m1.column1 + m1.column2 + m1.column3)
    FROM
        my_table m1
    WHERE
        m.group_id = m1.group_id
    GROUP BY
        m1.group_id
);
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587a9f/5)**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified exactly which values for column1, column2 and column3 must be returned.

```
select m.*,n.* from 
  m,
  (select 
    group_id as n_group_id, 
    max(column1+column2+column3) as n_total 
  from m group by group_id) as n 
where m.group_id=n_group_id and (column1+column2+column3)=n_total
```